# Shell script : Getting python: command not found error

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, shell, terminal

When I call Python script from shell script, it runs fine.

```
python script.py
```

But after I pulled the same script from Gerrit and then added code for calling Python script, then it gave me the below error :

```
./script.sh: line 126: python: command not found
```

Comment: Obviously the PATH inside script.sh is different from inside that shell script where it works well. Either fix the PATH in script.sh, or invoke python via the abs-path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like path problem.

Use `which python` in terminal to find your python path first. In my case it's in /usr/bin

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Then add the python path to path variable in your script.sh, e.g. put the following line in any place before you call python.

```
PATH+=:/usr/bin
```